# Who was the Greek philosopher that created a punctuation mark meaning "or so it seems to me at the moment"?

Tags: reference-request, ancient-philosophy

In high school I read about an ancient Greek philosopher who developed a punctuation mark that signified "or so it seems to me at the moment." This made it easy for this philosopher to qualify his statements. I just can't remember his name.

Comment: Let me try: Socrates, Aristotle, Platoon?

Comment: Aristophanes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristophanes_of_Byzantium)  invented punctuation marks, but until the Renaissance, it would seem that punctuation has been used only as a guide to recital rather than indicating semantics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sextus Empiricus, a Pyrrhonian Skeptic living probably in the second or third century CE, many of whose works survive, including the Outlines of Pyrrhonism, the best and fullest account we have of Pyrrhonian skepticism.

The "skeptical grammar", developed by Sextus Empiricus, ends every preposition with "so it seems to me at the moment".

He gives a negative account of the knowledge of his time, doubting everything including God and the possibility of knowledge.

Since he used the phrase so frequently, it is rather probable that he invented an abbreviation. Readers fluent in Greek may here [Sextus (Empiricus.),Immanuel Bekker: "Sextus Empiricus" (1842)](https://books.google.de/books?id=j-dEAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_v2_summary_r&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) find out what he used to express his sceptical attitude.

Sources:
http://www.philosophenlexikon.de/sextus-empiricus/
https://quizlet.com/118873950/soccio-archetypes-of-wisdom-ch-10-the-skeptic-david-hume-flash-cards/
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sextus-empiricus/
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sextus_Empiricus

Comment: Hi. Could you add to the answer some specific quotations, from the sources, that support what you claim about Sextus?

Comment: All I wrote above are essentially quotes, but shortened somewhat in order to avoid useless detail, in particular because I don't know whether it is the right answer at all. A reader understanding Greek should check Bekker's text.

Comment: Where did you take the following from? 
"The "skeptical grammar", developed by Sextus Empiricus, ends every preposition with "so it seems to me at the moment"."

Comment: https://quizlet.com/118873950/soccio-archetypes-of-wisdom-ch-10-the-skeptic-david-hume-flash-cards/ See second entry: "skeptical grammar"
    developed by Sextus Empiricus     It ends every preposition with "so it seems to me at the moment".

Comment: I wouldn't call this quizlet.com site a "source". Anyway I agree that some ancient skeptic seems to be the sought for philosopher. Maybe it was Pyrrho himself.